# Can't figure out pointer/array/string in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new to C and I have no idea how to handle this array:

```
char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
```

What does this line mean exactly? Is it a pointer to an array of chars?
The assignment given with this was to fill this array with multiple string tokens, but I don't understand how a char pointer can store a whole string?

Comment: it's an array of chars, sized to be MAX_LINE/2 + 1, e.g. `50/2 + 1` -> `26`.

Comment: It is an array of char pointers. The size is `MAX_LINE/2 +1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
```

`args` is an array of pointer to char of size `MAX_LINE / 2 + 1`.  Each element is a `char*`, i.e., each element may be a string.  You'll have to initialize them though (i.e., point them somewhere valid.)  For example, to read from stdin:

```
args[0] = malloc(some_size);
/* read a string from standard input */
fgets(args[0], some_size, stdin);
```

Comment: ... which may be being used as an array of strings; we'd have to see what values are being put into it.

Comment: how do I go about storing strings into this array?

Comment: @user3373372: Allocate each element with `malloc` and copy them in, point them to some other string, etc.  However you would populate any string in C. Added an example

Comment: @Ed S. so I tried args[0] = malloc(70); but the compiler says "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âmallocâ". Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3373372: `#include <stdlib.h>`. You need to include the declarations for the functions you use. You'll need `stdio.h` for `fgets`.  It's all in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That is basically an **array of pointers**. Each of the pointer points to a location that holds a **char** .

Take a look here for more details on handling it. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_array_of_pointers.htm